Asymptotic normality of the square root of the Unbiased Estimate of Variance from I.I.D. samples of $N(a\sigma, \sigma^2)$
Set-up
Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. according to the normal distribution $N(a\sigma, \sigma^2)$, where $a$ is a known positive constant and $0 < \sigma < \infty$.
Main Result
An obvious estimator of $\sigma$ is
$$
S := \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X}_n)}{n-1}}
$$
I want to show that
$$
\sqrt{n}[S - \sigma] \overset{L}{\to} N\left(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right).
$$
What I know
I know
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Var}[S] &= \mathbb{E}[S^2] - (\mathbb{E}[S])^2\\
&= \sigma^2 - \left(\sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}\right)^2
\end{align}
How can we show this result?
There is no indication that the deformations as they are can be shown...

Are you familiar with the delta-method?

yes, I know delta method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method), but Now I don't know how to use it well because it includes $n$ in the asymptotic variance.

$\mathbb{E}[S^2]=\sigma^2$ and $\mathbb{Var}[S^2] = \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$, so $\sqrt{n-1}[S^2-\sigma^2] \overset{L}{\to}N(0, 2\sigma^4)$ by CLT.

You're almost there. Seeing that you know that $$\sqrt{n}(S^2 - \sigma^2) \to N(0, 2\sigma^4)$$ in distribution, we may now apply the delta method. If $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$, then $g^\prime (\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{2\sigma}$, so that:
$$\sqrt{n}(S - \sigma) = \sqrt{n}(g(S^2) - g(\sigma^2)) \to N(0, 2\sigma^2 \cdot g^\prime (\sigma^2)^2) = N\left(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$$
